# Datatables Not Loading Nested Objects Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Trying to get my ajax to load into data tables. I want to load 2 tables from the same ajax call but I can't even get 1 to load first. Let's get some snippet action going...

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tablepress-1").DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: '/api/?action=getStats',
      dataSrc: 'data',
      "deferRender": true
    },
    "columns": [{
        "instances": "Strategy"
      },
      {
        "instances": "Exchange"
      },
      {
        "instances": "Trades"
      },
      {
        "instances": "PL"
      },
      {
        "instances": "Uptime"
      }
    ]


  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="tablepress-1" class="tablepress tablepress-id-1">
  <caption style="caption-side:bottom;text-align:left;border:none;background:none;margin:0;padding:0;"><a href="https://pinebot.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=tablepress&action=edit&table_id=1">Edit</a></caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row-1">
      <td class="column-1">Strategy</td>
      <td class="column-2">Exchange</td>
      <td class="column-3">Trades</td>
      <td class="column-4">PL</td>
      <td class="column-5">Uptime</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Since stack snippets don't support ajax data, I'll paste it here:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"instances":[{"Strategy":"...","Exchange":"...","Trades":"...","PL":"...","Uptime":"..."}],"trades":[{"Open":"...","Strategy":"...","Exchange":"...","Direction":"...","Size":"...","PL":"...","Close":"...","ID":"..."}]},"meta":{"botOnline":true,"threadCount":0,"balance":0.0028}}
```

Right now I just have my script outputting `...` for each field. What happens is that the table headings disappear and no data ever gets loaded into the table.

I tried setting up a fiddle with the data source but it's my first time trying to use the echo feature. Maybe someone else knows how to do that: https://jsfiddle.net/Trioxin/kjhtn7wm/6/

I can't imagine what's wrong here. I thought I specified the json format properly but it appears not.

Comment: It is not so clear what data exactly you want to use.  You cannot combine `instances` and `trades` since they have different fields / prop names; and since all your data contain `"..."` it is not clear if it is possible to map parts of `trades` objects into corresponding `instances` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Regarding cross domain AJAX sources in jsfiddles you can use **http://myjson.com**
2. Your "table headings" disappear because they are not table headings. They are just a `<tbody>` row that will be removed as soon DataTables get some data. Do this instead:

   ```
   <thead>
     <tr class="row-1">
       <th class="column-1">Strategy</th>
       <th class="column-2">Exchange</th>
       <th class="column-3">Trades</th>
       <th class="column-4">PL</th>
       <th class="column-5">Uptime</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   ```
3. You must either pass an array of objects or point to the path of that array, like `dataSrc: data.instances`. You could also have `dataSrc: function(data) { return data.data.instances }`
4. You define which object property that should be mapped into which column through the `data` option like `{ data: "Strategy" }`:

   ```
   columns: [
     { data: "Strategy" },
     { data: "Exchange" },
     { data: "Trades" },
     { data: "PL" },
     { data: "Uptime" }
   ]
   ```

forked fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/hfc10sxt/**

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to update 2 datatables with 1 ajax call? I can't seem to get it working. About to pose the question.

Comment: here's that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303556/multiple-datatables-with-1-ajax-call-not-working